# Potential bug in body validation pop-up

Tags: bug, edits, error-message

Just now I tried to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022671/hibernate-schemaexport-performs-a-hhh000389-unsuccessful-error) to remove the urgent begging, so I took out this line:

> Urgently waiting for a solution, thanks in advance.

When I did so, even prior to submitting the edit, a pop-up complained about the first line, saying:

> Body cannot contain "I encounte"

Hmm, I thought - that's odd. Alright, I'll change "encountered" to "discovered", and the machine replied:

> Body cannot contain "I discover"

Does the hamster's wheel need a bit of tuning? `:-)`.

Comment: No matter what I change, it tells me "body cannot contain "10 first letters of the post".... not sure THIS is what's blocking the post. May be something else, and the error message only shows the first part?

Comment: I took out the "urgency" clause, as well as, the first sentence *"I encountered this problem when initializing tables via hibernate, but some of those tables fail to create due to this kind of error."* and it let the edit go through. I tried to put that first edit back in and I got the same message as above. Had to rollback :\

Comment: I was able to edit out only the begging by hitting enter at the beginning of the first line.  Essentially making the first line empty, although visually after the edit there is no empty line at the top of the question.

Comment: Good hack @rogerdeuce! I edited to accept your change, and interestingly I had to re-apply it - I wonder if it gets trimmed in the editor?

Comment: Good sleuthing @Braiam - that sounds like the same bug.